# spark query results impacted by shuffle partition count

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below code that groups the salaries

```
# this is a sample to learn about shuffle partitions config property

def getDataFrame():
  data = [('Eric', 'history', 4000), ('Adam', '\Economics', 3000), ('Angela', 'Science', 6000)]
  dataDF = spark.createDataFrame(data, 'name STRING, dept STRING, salary INT')

  # order by and group by triggers shuffle leading to shuffle partitions
  groupedDF = dataDF.orderBy("salary",ascending=True).groupBy("salary").count()
  groupedDF.show()
  print("Number of partitions: ",groupedDF.rdd.getNumPartitions())


spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 200)
getDataFrame()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 80)
getDataFrame()
```

I expect the results to be same as the data, aggregation functions are same but it seems the results are impacted by shuffle partitions. .

[image: Here is the output]
Can someone explain the behavior?

Comment: A `groupBy` on a `DataFrame` results in a `RelationalGroupedDataset` which like DataFrame is not supposed to preserve the order of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `orderBy()` in addition to `groupBy()` to get same result even after updating your shuffle partitions.